# Good open source 'Social Network' components for Joomla CMS

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, social-networking

Im trying to find a open source Social Network component for Joomla.

There is a free version of 'Community builder' but everytime i download .. the downloaded file is corrupted.

Any pointers for good / customizable open source 'social network' component for joomla CMS.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JomSocial](http://www.jomsocial.com/) is as good as it gets and it is open source. You do have to pay for it, but it is well worth the investment. If by open source you mean free, then there are no good options other than Community Builder.

Comment: I don't think we can say that software is open source if you have to pay for it. Calling it commercial and source-available would be more appropriate.